Problema para desconectar registros en NestJs con Prisma ORM
Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Nest y tengo problemas cuando quiero hacer un patch sobre un registro. Este registro es un producto que esta alojado en una tabla llamada Product y se relaciona de manera n:m con una tabla que contiene las categorias, Category.
El tema es que no logro actualizar las categorias. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando envie un objeto con un arreglo en la propiedad 'categories', las categorias que no estan en ese arreglo sean aliminadas. Por ejemplo, estoy implementando este service:



import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma.service';
import { UpdateProductDto } from 'src/products/dto/update-product.dto';

@Injectable()
export class UpdateProductByIdService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async updateProduct(id: number, productBody: UpdateProductDto) {
    const product = await this.prisma.product.update({
      where: { id: id },
      data: {
        name: productBody.name,
        description: productBody.description,
        price: productBody.price,
        stock: productBody.stock,
        mark: productBody.mark,
        model: productBody.model,
        color: productBody.color,
        active: productBody.active,
        categories: {
          disconnect: productBody.categories
            .map(async (categoryId) => {
              const categoriesIds = await this.prisma.product
                .findUnique({
                  where: { id },
                  include: { categories: true },
                })
              let catsToDelete = categoriesIds.categories.filter( catIds => {
                return catIds.id !== categoryId
              })
              return catsToDelete;
            }),
          connect: productBody.categories.map((id) => ({ id })),
        },
      },
    });

    return product;
  }
}



Este es el json que estoy enviando por body por patch:


{
  "name": "Producto 4 actualizado",
  "description": "le quite la categoria 1 y 2, solo queda la cat 4",
  "price": 10.99,
  "stock": 100,
  "mark": "Brand",
  "model": "Model XYZ",
  "color": "Red",
  "active": true,
  "categories": [4]
}



el id lo envio por param.
y lo que recibo cuando hago un get by id es esto:


{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Producto 4 actualizado",
    "description": "le quite la categoria 1 y 2, solo queda la cat 4",
    "price": 10.99,
    "stock": 100,
    "mark": "Brand",
    "model": "Model XYZ",
    "color": "Red",
    "active": true,
    "createdAt": "2024-04-27T20:59:20.416Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-04-28T19:55:31.126Z",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Medias",
            "description": "Medias",
            "imageId": null,
            "createdAt": "2024-04-26T21:48:38.494Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-04-26T21:48:38.494Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Gorras",
            "description": "Gorras",
            "imageId": null,
            "createdAt": "2024-04-26T21:49:13.563Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-04-26T21:49:13.563Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Categoria 1",
            "description": "Editada",
            "imageId": null,
            "createdAt": "2024-04-26T01:20:49.479Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-04-26T22:16:42.537Z"
        }
    ]
}



cabe aclarar que se actualiza el producto pero no la relacion con las categorias.

Echándole un vistazo rápido y a falta de que compartas el error que te indica VS Code (es importante compartir los errores para poderte ayudar de forma más fácil), el error que tienes es que map regresa un arreglo y async regresa una promesa, entonces lo que te regresa es un arreglo de promesas, en este caso puedes usar Promise.all() para resolver todas las promesas antes de seguir con la ejecución del código.
Puedes encontrar en la documentación lo que hace cada uno, empezando por map:
Valor devuelto

Un nuevo array en la que cada elemento es el resultado
de ejecutar callback.

Mientras que async:

Cuando se llama a una función async, esta devuelve un elemento
Promise.

No he usado PrismaORM pero con TypeORM usualmente haría algo así (el código obviamente adaptado a Prisma)

Obtener categorías de productos:

 const categories = await this.prisma.product.findUnique({
      where: { id },
      include: { categories: true },
    });

Filtramos dos veces para reutilizar la búsqueda de categories y evitar buscar al momento de actualizar.

Filtrar categorías para desconectar:

const categoriesToDisconnect = productCategories.categories
      .filter(category => !productBody.categories.includes(category.id))
      .map(category => ({ id: category.id }));


Filtrar categorías para conectar:

const categoriesToConnect = productBody.categories
      .filter(categoryId => !productCategories.categories.some(category => category.id === categoryId))
      .map(categoryId => ({ id: categoryId }));


Actualizar producto:
Uso el operador spread para esparcir productBody, ya que tienen el mismo nombre.

const product = await this.prisma.product.update({
      where: { id: id },
      data: {
        ...productBody,
        categories: {
          disconnect: categoriesToDisconnect,
          connect: categoriesToConnect,
        },
      },
    });

